# SQL - identifying function parameters when calling table-vauled function

Tags: sql, sql-server

One typically calls a SQL table-valued function with parameters like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM myfuntion('1/1/2017')  -- where the only parameter is a `@date` parameter
```

Is it possible to explicitly identify the parameter when setting it?  Something like:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM myfuntion(date='1/1/2017')  --pseudo code
```

I ask because, sometimes, a function has many parameters, and it's easy to mistake the order of them when calling a function.

In this case, it would be great have something like:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM myfuntion(date='1/1/2017', par2='foo', par3='bar', ...)  - pseudo code
```

Comment: No you can't do that. It is allowed when calling stored procedures because procedure allow for optional parameters but functions (both scalar and table valued) do not.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. me too curious about this. waiting for someone's answer. it is possible to pass parameter name in stored procedure. if there are more parameter you want to pass then use parameter with XML data type.

Comment: @IamMOHIT, Sean Lange already answered it, so I wouldn't wait much longer. :-)